# How to give php script POST arguments via command line

Tags: php

I am debugging a php script that will be called by a javascript function and that have POST arguments. I would like to test it in command line mode. I know it is possible doing it with the php -a option. But once in the interactive mode how to I set up the arguments? And how do I call my php? I can't neither remenber nor find how to do it.

My php script is:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['string'];
$fname = $_POST['file'];
$dir=$_POST['dir'];
mkdir($dir);
$file = fopen($fname, 'w');
fwrite($file, $dir."\n");
fwrite($file, $data."\n");
fwrite($file, "/var/www/html/ChemAlive_app/SOFTWARE/utilities/"."\n");
fclose($file);
$saved = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");        // save old value
$newld = "/usr/local/NWChem/lib/";  // extra paths to add
if ($saved) { $newld .= ":$saved"; }           // append old paths if any
putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$newld");
$saved = getenv("PATH");        // save old value
$newld = "/usr/local/NWChem/bin/";  // extra paths to add
if ($saved) { $newld .= ":$saved"; }           // append old paths if any
putenv("PATH=$newld");
exec("cd $dir ;  /var/www/html/ChemAlive_app/SOFTWARE/ChemAliveExec/ReactionThermo ".$fname);
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are happy to use a separate console command, [use `curl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822879/calling-curl-with-post-data-and-headers-on-command-line). You can do it with PHP as well, but cURL via the console is more succinct.

Comment: I concur, trying to reproduce a web server environment is much too complicated when you can simply reproduce the HTTP request instead.

Comment: that seems promising, how does that works?

Comment: Browsers aren't the only things that can produce HTTP requests. curl is a command line utility that can do the same. There are myriads of tools available for this. Google curl and/or "REST API test tool" or such.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
<?php
// check to see if php called from cmd line 
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
       //take vars from cmd line args argv[0] is script name
       $data = $argv[1];
       $fname = $argv[2];
       $dir = $argv[3];
} else {
       $data = $_POST['string'];
       $fname = $_POST['file'];
       $dir=$_POST['dir'];
}
```

then call the script on the command line with

`/path/to/php /path/to/script.php 'some data' 'filename' 'dirname'`